# What is difference between Lease Timeout and HealthCheck Timeout in AlwaysON?

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, clustering, failover, timeout

this question was asked twice here but still there is no satisfied answer. Could someone explain the main difference between these two timeouts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google took me straight here :-

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/availability-group-lease-healthcheck-timeout?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Health checks these 5 components :-
system, resource, query processing, io subsystem and events
Lease
The lease mechanism is used as a Looks-Alive validation between the Cluster resource host and the SQL Server process